# TypeError: db.collection(...).doc(...).collection(...).doc.where is not a function

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

/Users/fksH8NQCdXWSvfMGXd1YiYocnTq2/Dashboard/TextBox0

```
clientDb.collection("Users").doc(props.uid).collection("Dashboard").doc.where('name', '>=', 'Text').delete();
```

I'm not sure what's wrong. I can directly delete it using `.doc("TextBox0").delete()` but I cant delete it from the above query. help?

Answer (score 2):

Invalid syntax remove `.doc` and try this:

```js
clientDb.collection("Users").doc(props.uid).collection("Dashboard").where('name', '>=', 'Text').delete();
```